Power Apps If Statement
I have two text input boxes for a user to fill in. I want to make it so the submit button does not work until both text input boxes are filled in. I assume some sort of IF statement on the displaymode for the submit button. I tried using the following formula
IF(TextInput1.Text & TextInput2.Text <>"",DisplayMode.Edit,DisplayMode.Disabled)
However this formula does not work, it allows the user to hit submit if only one text box box is filled in and i need both boxes to be filled in in order to proceed. Thanks for th help!

This question is similar to: How do I use two functions in power apps?. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

You can use this on submit button
If((IsBlank(TextInput3.Text) Or IsBlank(TextInput4.Text)),Notify("Required fields can not be empty"),SubmitForm(EditForm1));

If((!IsBlank(TextInput3.Text) And !IsBlank(TextInput4.Text)),Back());


As per information provided, you can try below formula in "Display Mode" property to enable the submit button only if both the textboxes are filled
If(Or(IsBlank(TextInput1.Text),IsBlank(TextInput2.Text)),DisplayMode.Disabled,DisplayMode.Edit)

Hope this helps :)
